# How can I connect the top loop to the down loop with faces

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hey I want to connect the bottom loop with the top loop so that it forms a solid.

I have tried selecting multiple vertices and pressing F but that just creates a large face which I do not want.
I have tried using grid fill bu that doesn't work either.
The solution that seems to work is by selecting four vertices and pressing F and then selecting the next 4 and pressing F and on and on. That just takes too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Bridge edge loops command:

1. Select both loops:
   [image]

2.Then click space and type bridge edge loops:
[image]

3. Click on it and its done:
   [image]