# Filling a Void between two 2D objects (Meeple)

Tags: objects, image, 2d

I am trying to create [Meeple](https://topshelf-fun.com/pages/frontpage) in Blender.  I have the portrait of the meeple(s) designed as 2D images.

How far have I made it... I have an image inserted into Blender, I put a copy of that spaced away from it... I just want to know if I can fill the void in between those objects to quickly make a 3D object instead of shaping objects until it matches the shape...

Comment: Sadly there is no way to quickly create 3D models from 2D images in Blender. However, there are tricks to accomplishing the modeling of whatever it is you are creating quickly and/or easily. See this similar question on Blender Stack Exchange:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture/63256#63256

Comment: Read: [How do I connect the top loop with down loop with faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49940/how-can-i-connect-the-top-loop-to-the-down-loop-with-faces/49943#49943)

Answer (score 1):

Use a vectorial drawing program to trace the shape as path. Save as SVG.

[image]

Import to blender as SVG. (File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics)

[image]

Use the Geometry section of the curve to create extrusion.

[image]

Done.

Read:

[How to model an object with width and depth, based only on an image that shows the outline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/any-suggestions-on-how-to-model-it-i-tried-few-but-couldnt-find-the-perfect-on/183188#183188)